# How to get near by places with in radius of 5 kilometer from current location?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

What i have done so far is that i m successfully  getting the near by places like Atm Banks Restaurant from the whole twin cities 
But i just want to show the nearby places that is with in 5 kilometer to the current user location i have searched a lot but could not find any answer to my question

"This is my code where i m getting the places by names "

```
myLocation = new MyLocation(context);

    if (myLocation.isLocationAvailable() && myLocation.getUserLocation() != null)
    {
        current_location_lat =  myLocation.getUserLocation().latitude;

        current_location_lng =  myLocation.getUserLocation().longitude;

        latStr = current_location_lat + "";

        longStr = current_location_lng + "";

        myLatLng = new LatLng(current_location_lat, current_location_lng);

        //url = url_part1 + latStr + "," + longStr + url_part2;

        Log.d("LATITUDE", String.valueOf(current_location_lat));

        Log.d("LONGITUDE", String.valueOf(current_location_lng));


        new PlaceTask(context, positionOfType, latStr, longStr, new onTaskDoneListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onTaskDone(JSONObject jsonObject) 
            {
                if(jsonObject!=null)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        JSONObject obj = jsonObject;//new JSONObject(jsonObject);

                        String status = obj.getString("status");

                        if(status.equals("OK"))
                        {
                            JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("results");

                            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
                            {
                                double lat = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat");

                                double lng = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng"); 

                                String place_name = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");

                                String vicinity = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("vicinity");


                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

                                map.put("placeName", place_name);

                                map.put("vicinity", vicinity);

                                map.put("lat", String.valueOf(lat));

                                map.put("lng", String.valueOf(lng));

                                list.add(map);
                                Global_Var.latvalue.add(i,String.valueOf(lat));
                                Global_Var.longtvalue.add(i,String.valueOf(lng));
                            }

                            NearByPlaceAdapter adapter = new NearByPlaceAdapter(context, list);

                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (JSONException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Response is Null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }).execute();

        //showSearchDialog(map);    
    }               
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Please Enable Location Services and GPS From your Device", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

MyLocation

```
public MyLocation(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    try {
        manager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            islocavailable = true;
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000,
                    1, this);
            Log.d("gps enabled", "gps enabled");
            String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

            Location lastKnownLocation = manager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
            userLocation = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                    lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
            Log.d("gps disabled 1", lastKnownLocation.getLatitude() + ","
                    + lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
            // map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation,
            // 15));
            // islocavailable=true;
        } else if (manager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            islocavailable = true;
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, this);
            String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

            Location lastKnownLocation = manager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
            userLocation = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                    lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
            // map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation,
            // 15));
            Log.d("gps disabled 2", lastKnownLocation.getLatitude() + ","
                    + lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
            // islocavailable=true;
        } else {
            Log.d("all disabled", "all disabled");

            islocavailable = false;
            // showAlertDialog();
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to use this google api for nearby search with valid parameters. Check out this link it will help you https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: will you further elaborate please what do you mean by valid parameters ?

Comment: Check out this link i have given it describes all.You will find a web service which you have to run and it requires some parameters

Comment: ok let me give it a try

Comment: You need to add `radius` which defines the distance (in meters) within which to return place results. Check this link https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

Comment: @AbhayBohra just clear one thing i m using google maps api v2 to do all these tasks what you ahve provided me is Google Places API Web Service is it the same or do i need to change that i m confused in it ?

Comment: you have to run an async task and call that api with the required parameter described in that link.then it will give you the result in json format.After that you have to parse that result that contains nearby locations.

Comment: @AbhayBohra ok let me give it a try thank you for quick reply

Comment: The Google Places API Web Service is a service that returns information about places and you need to do what @AbhayBohra had told you and Google Maps API is an API which provides Google Maps and related functionality.

Comment: @HassanJamil thank you let me try this one :)

Comment: Have you solved your problem?